# Regression with dummy and quantitative variables in R

Tags: r, regression

For example if we have a dummy variable A and a quantitative variable B, we can use the production *lm(Y ~ A * B)* to do the regression. But how can I code if I have many dummy and quantitative variables(A1,A2,A3... and B1,B2,B3...)?

Comment: I think `cbind(A1,A2)` will work.

Comment: Yeah, good solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Frank noted in the commments, you can use `cbind` to group variables:

```
set.seed(1243)
df <- data.frame(a1= sample(c(0,1), size= 100, replace=T),
             a2= sample(c(0,1), size= 100, replace=T),
             a3= sample(c(0,1), size= 100, replace=T),
             b1= rnorm(100), b2= rnorm(100), b3= rnorm(100), n=rnorm(100))
summary(lm(n ~ cbind(a1,a2,a3) * cbind(b1,b2,b3), data=df))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question and A1, A2, A3 etc and B1, B2, and B3 are their own separate variables, you just make sure they are in the same data frame and do

```
lm(Y ~ A1 + A2 + A3 + B1 + B2 + B3, data = df)
```

and so forth.   You just add/delete the variables as needed.

However, if you're asking how to do multiple iterations of a regression based on certain subsets of the variable (like doing a regression only where A = 1 and B = 1, then where A = 2 and B = 1, etc.) then I'll need to know more information about your data frame to help with that.